# How good are steam cleaners compared to vacuum cleaners?

Tags: cleaning, steam

Are steam cleaners better then the vacuum cleaners for cleaning carpets and kitchen?

Does steam cleaners can also do vacuum cleaning?

Comment: Check out [this page](http://www.austeamappliances.com/products(suction).html) but I don't know about the quality of a combo vac/steamer

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to get a comparison on apples and oranges as both work on entirely different principles:

steam cleaners use steam to sterilize and loosen dirt for mopping up with a rag which may or may not be attached to the steam cleaner

vacuum cleaners just suck up loose dirt

vacuum cleaners are better for carpets while steam cleaners are better for smooth floors

Comment: Let's be clear: "fake" steam cleaners (like common supermarket rentals) spray soap then vacuum it up.